# Hardhat Can't resolve 'console' on react project

Tags: web3js, mainnet, buidler

I have a react project and initialized hardhat config then installed the necessary packages but I am
getting error when I require hardhat on my project
`const hre = require("hardhat");`

This is error message when the project is compiling

```
./node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/integrations/console.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'console' in 'C:\Users\sss\OneDrive\Desktop\my-react\node_modules\@sentry\node\esm\integrations'
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you requiring hardhat from your React code? Because that won't work, hardhat is meant to be executed with node.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and what fixed it for me was changing my imports statement for ethers from `import { ethers } from 'hardhat';` to `import { ethers } from 'ethers';`